# Azure Repos, remote with url to create pull request

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

I've been using git on command line for quite a while in BitBucket and Github, but recently I started using Azure Repos.

One feature that I'm used to is, whenever I push a new branch to the upstream for the first time, the remote will give me the url to create a pull request for that particular branch.

### Examples:

BitBucket:

```
$     git push --set-upstream origin test-1
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 266 bytes | 266.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote:
remote: Create pull request for test-1:
remote:   https://bitbucket.org/xxxxxxxxxxx/test-pr-message/pull-requests/new?source=test-1&t=1
remote:
To https://bitbucket.org/xxxxxxxxxxx/test-pr-message.git
 * [new branch]      test-1 -> test-1
Branch 'test-1' set up to track remote branch 'test-1' from 'origin'.
```

GitHub:

```
$     git push --set-upstream origin test-1
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 266 bytes | 266.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), completed with 1 local object.
remote:
remote: Create a pull request for 'test-1' on GitHub by visiting:
remote:      https://github.com/xxxxxxx/test-pr-message/pull/new/test-1
remote:
To https://github.com/xxxxxxx/test-pr-message.git
 * [new branch]      test-1 -> test-1
Branch 'test-1' set up to track remote branch 'test-1' from 'origin'.
```

However, the Azure repos service does not return this url exactly, it returns just the repository URL and you have to go there, select the branch you just pushed to the upstream and then create the PR.

Example from Azure Repo:

```
$     git push --set-upstream origin test-1
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 276 bytes | 276.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Analyzing objects... (3/3) (5 ms)
remote: Storing packfile... done (41 ms)
remote: Storing index... done (30 ms)
To https://dev.azure.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/test-pr-message/_git/test-pr-message
 * [new branch]      test-1 -> test-1
Branch 'test-1' set up to track remote branch 'test-1' from 'origin'.
```

Is this a config or something that I could change in the interface somewhere or this is just a feature that azure doesn't have and the others do?

**Edit:**

As pointed by @hross this is not available as of now in Azure Repos. One way of getting to the branch (not exactly the pr creation, but Azure will mention the branch was just pushed and offer to create the PR) is this one:

`echo $(git remote -v | awk 'NR==1{print $2 "?version=GB"}')$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)`

So I added it to AutoHotkey as the command `gpush` so when I type that in my git bash it will give me the address. I can also use as a quick way to navigate to whatever branch and repo I'm working even if I don't want to create a PR.

```
::gpush::echo {$}(git remote -v | awk 'NR==1{{}print {$}2 "?version=GB"{}}'){$}(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is just a feature that Azure Repos does not currently support (but I'm on the dev team so I added it to our backlog).

Comment: Thanks for adding it to the backlog, I just use command line to use git so it will make a difference to me. I'll edit my question and add the "workaround" I'm using for now.

Comment: Thanks, anywhere we can track this?

Comment: @hross do we have any update regarding this feature? thanks

Comment: That item went to the backlog to die.

Answer (score 0):

The pull request URL in Azure Devops has a standard format.
You can use this along with git hooks to output a PR link to the terminal on git push.

Here's the script I built. It is saved in `.git/hooks/pre-push`.

It assumes you want to merge into the develop branch, but you could easily tweak it to take the target branch from a command line argument if you want.

To get the variables for constructing the URL (especially the repo id) its easiest to create a pull request manually and then copy and paste the values from the PR url into the script.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Get these variables by looking at the URL of an existing pull request.
DEVOPS_ORGANISATION="[INSERT_YOUR_ORG]"
PROJECT="[INSERT_YOUR_PROJECT]"
REPO_NAME="[YOUR_REPO_NAME]"
REPO_ID="[YOUR_REPO_ID]"

SOURCE_BRANCH=`git branch --show-current`
TARGET_BRANCH="develop"

PULL_REQUEST_URL="https://dev.azure.com/$DEVOPS_ORGANISATION/$PROJECT/_git/$REPO_NAME/pullrequestcreate?sourceRef=$SOURCE_BRANCH&targetRef=$TARGET_BRANCH&sourceRepositoryId=$REPO_ID&targetRepositoryId=$REPO_ID"

WHITE="\033[0m"
GREEN="\033[32m"
echo
echo -e "Create a pull request: ${GREEN} $PULL_REQUEST_URL ${WHITE}"
echo
```

After saving the file remember to make it executable  (eg. `chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-push`).